# VBA: Import Specific Variable Named Sheet in Workbook of Sheets to Access Table?

Tags: vba, ms-access, excel

I'm looking for a way to import a specific tab into my Access table. Normally I do a TransferSpreadsheet type of code, so this is rather new to me.

I need the user to be able to open the file from any directory - followed by have the program import a specific spreadsheet that can have a semi-variable name.

**The spreadsheet that needs to be imported is always " Details".** So obviously, right now the file would contain a tab called July Details. So my logic with this bit of code was to find the spreadsheet with LIKE (or *) Detail. I'm not sure if this works however, and I'm not sure how best to transfer this to my Access Table since I'm so used to TransferSpreadsheet. Any help is appreciated!

```
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook

ImportFileName = cmdFileDialog("Select File to Import: ")
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=ImportFileName)

For Each Sheet In wb2.Sheets
        If Sheet.Name Like Detail Then
            Sheet.Copy After:=wb1.Sheets(wb1.Sheets.Count)
        End If
Next Sheet

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, DataTable, ImportFileName, True, DataRange
```

EDIT: Let me clarify: Once I find the sheet with *Details* in it, I am not sure how to import it into an Access table like I need. That is my last problem with this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a response for the last part of your question!
To upload a table in Excel to an Access Table you will need the following:

1. ADODB library (Microsoft ActiveX Data Object 2.x)
2. array operations

You will be using the following objects and methods in ADODB:

1. Connection
2. Recordset
3. AddNew

Here is a generic example of using ADODB to append new records to a table in Access:

(If you have more than one record that you need to add, you will need to write a loop to create different array containing the values and call the AddNew function repeatedly. As far as I know ADODB does not support batch upload of records*correct me if i'm wrong here)

```
Dim objcon As ADODB.Connection
Dim objrec As ADODB.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strCon As String

'important strings you'll need
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM " & TABLE_NAME & ";"
strCon = "DSN=MS Access Database;DBQ=" & FULLPATH_OF_DATABASE & ";"

'open your connection to the database
Set objcon = New ADODB.Connection
objcon.Open strCon

'open your recordset from database
Set objrec = New ADODB.Recordset
objrec.Open strSQL, objcon, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

'adding a new record
objrec.AddNew Array("FIELD_1", "FIELD_2", "FIELD_3"), Array("Value1", "Value2", "Value3")

Set objrec = Nothing
Set objcon = Nothing
```

Let me know if that helps!

Answer (score -1):

Looks like I found a way with the DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet in combination. Thank you everyone. If this is a little ugly feel free to correct or give me a more proper way.

```
ImportFileName = cmdFileDialog("Select File to import : ")
DoCmd.SetWarnings False

Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlWrk As Object
Dim xlSheet As Object
Dim db As Database
Dim SheetName As String

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlWrk = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(ImportFileName)
Set db = CurrentDb

For Each Sheet In xlWrk.Sheets
    If Sheet.Name Like "*Detail*" Then
        Set xlSheet = xlWrk.Sheets(Sheet.Name)
        SheetName = Sheet.Name
    End If
Next Sheet

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet _
    transfertype:=acImport, _
    TableName:="tblImport", _
    FileName:=ImportFileName, _
    HasFieldNames:=True, _
    Range:=SheetName & "!A1:BM" & ls_last_row
```